# XSLT transformation from RDF to html

Tags: xml, xslt, rdf

I am trying to transform an RDF file to HTML using XSLT.

I am using the template that i've found on the web:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1164

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
  xmlns:foo="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/foo:channel"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/rdf:RDF/foo:channel">
        <h3><xsl:value-of select="foo:title"/></h3>
        <p><xsl:value-of select="foo:description"/></p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/rdf:RDF/foo:item"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/rdf:RDF/foo:item">
        <li>
            <a href="{foo:link}" title="{substring(dc:date, 0, 11)}"><xsl:value-of select="foo:title"/></a>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="foo:description" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works perfectly with an RDF file like that:
(Here is the **link** to the complete file)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2232733/rdfexample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- generator="wordpress/1.2" -->
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
>
<channel rdf:about="http://www.wasab.dk/morten/blog/rdf">
    <title>Binary Relations</title>
    <link>http://www.wasab.dk/morten/blog</link>
    <description>Reflections on the web</description>
    <dc:language>en</dc:language>
    <dc:date>2004-05-29T23:02:37Z</dc:date>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://wordpress.org/?v=1.2"/>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>
    <sy:updateBase>2000-01-01T12:00+00:00</sy:updateBase>
    <items>
<rdf:Seq>
<rdf:li rdf:resource="http://www.wasab.dk/morten/blog/archives/2004/05/30/wordpress-plugin-linkifier"/>
...
<rdf:li rdf:resource="http://www.wasab.dk/morten/blog/archives/2004/05/20/yet-another-semweb-blogger"/>
</rdf:Seq>
</items>
</channel>
<item rdf:about="http://www.wasab.dk/morten/blog/archives/2004/05/30/wordpress-plugin-linkifier">
    <title>WordPress Plugin: Linkifier</title>
```

However, I can't make it work for an RDF\XML that i get from lastfm.rdfize.com/:
(here is the **link** for the file)
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2232733/metallica_rdf_xml.xml

It has a different structure and I can't figure out what tags in XSTL should i use to make an HTML from it:

```
rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:terms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
  xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
  xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
  xmlns:mo="http://purl.org/ontology/mo/"
  xmlns:ov="http://open.vocab.org/terms/"
  xmlns:event="http://purl.org/NET/c4dm/event.owl#"
  xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
  xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#">

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://lastfm.rdfize.com/artists/Metallica">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/ontology/mo/MusicArtist"/>
    <rdfs:label>Metallica</rdfs:label>
  ...
```

So my question is - how should I form an XSLT to process my RDF?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Both texts are severyly malformed - incomplete XML documents. 2. There is no question asked at all. Please, correct.

Comment: I have provided the links above - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2232733/rdfexample.xml
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2232733/metallica_rdf_xml.xml

The question is - how to correctly process my rdf?

Comment: Maybe if you provide a desired output, someone will post an stylesheet example for your input sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main problem is that your stylesheet is far too domain specific.  RDF/XML is a very complex serialization that allows multiple ways of stating things.  Your stylesheet is referring to very specific element names which are only valid in a very narrow range of RDF/XML documents e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/rdf:RDF/foo:item">
```

The above attempts to match the root level `<rdf:RDF>` elements which is actually not mandatory - it's acceptable for alternative root elements to be used or for `<rdf:RDF>` to be embedded inside other XML elements provided there is only one.

Then it attempts to match the `<foo:item>` element which is a document specific ID, this element name could be absolutely anything from the general `<rdf:Description>` to the previous example.

**Solution**

**Don't** attempt to transform RDF/XML with a stylesheet as invariably any stylesheet you write which can transform a full range of RDF/XML documents will be so ridicously complex as to make no sense whatsoever.

*Instead* find yourself a good RDF library (there's one/more out there for most major languages) which provides an RDF/XML parser and a HTML or HTML+RDFa writer and use those.  If you want to control the HTML output as a base use the library's HTML writer as a guide and adapt it or just apply a CSS stylesheet over its output.

Comment: Thank you!
Could you point me to one of those that have an HTML writer?
I am using Jena at the moment but Jena allows only export to XML and TURTLE.

Comment: You are right about the "don't use a general stylesheet" recommendation. RDF is an attempt for a standar "relationship" vocavulary plus a holder for a standar "sematic" vocabulary. But, you can use a general stylesheet as long as you know how to deal with this two fields.

Comment: @Hippopotamus There are RDFa writers for Jena available but they aren't part of the standard jena distribution

Comment: I doubt there would be a generic HTML writer, since there's no standard way of representing random RDF as HTML.  Instead, it's probably best to read the entire RDF file into an application (using Jena, or librdf.org if you want to use C), and write it as HTML in your own custom way.

Comment: No but there is RDFa which specifies how to embed RDF into HTML so you can use an existing RDFa writer to provide a skeleton which you can then customise to output HTML in a format you desire or use it as a guide on how to embed RDFa onto your HTML

Answer (score -1):

Agree with Rob that you should look into a good RDF API, but you might also want to check out [grddl](http://www.w3.org/TR/grddl/).

Comment: -1.  GRDDL is trying to solve the opposite problem: converting XML to RDF, and does so with XSLT.  It's no use for converting RDF/XML to other XML formats.