# How to display rdf file in web browser

Tags: java, rdf, semantic-web

I have some web services which return RDF file. Now I need to display this RDF file like: http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin. Is there some Java library which can do this, because now it looks like just as XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Pubby](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/pubby/), a Java webapp that can connect to an RDF data source and presents an HTML view. Usually the RDF data is stored in a SPARQL store, but you can also just load it from an RDF file using the `conf:loadRDF` configuration option.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jena](http://incubator.apache.org/jena/), it will parse the RDF into Java structures which you can use to generate HTML. Also see the answers here: [XSLT transformation from RDF to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180840/xslt-transformation-from-rdf-to-html)

Comment: I already using JENA to create rdf file and then covert to string. Can you be more cncretive how I can generate html from java structure ?

Comment: It's up to you, really. I'd look at how Pubby in the other answer does it, or maybe use it directly.

Comment: I cannot use pubby because I am creating RDF  file in my application and this I want to convert to html.