# How to publish rdf file on the web

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I create some RDF file with JENA. Now I need publich this RDF file on the web but I dont know how. It might look like this page: http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin or just example. Important is that other RDF tool can read these file as RDF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a website or some webspace somewhere? Just save the file as RDF/XML with `.rdf` file extension, or as Turtle with `.ttl` extension, and upload it to the website. Now it's published on the Web, and you can access it with RDF tools like Marbles and Tabulator, get it indexed in RDF search engines like Sindice, and so on.

If you want the file to work not just in RDF tools but also in normal web browsers, then it's a bit more complicated as you need your server to implement “HTTP content negotiation”. One way to do this is with [Pubby](http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/pubby/), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170588/how-to-display-rdf-file-in-web-browser/10171970#10171970).