# Deserialization XML elements which are References (RDF Resources)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, rdf

I have XML file where some elements are resources inside.
like

```
<cim:BusbarSection rdf:ID="Busbar_05" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"       xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2001/CIM-schema-cim10#">
<cim:Naming.name>30189P0205_Busbar_01</cim:Naming.name>
<cim:Equipment.MemberOf_EquipmentContainter rdf:resource="#VL_05" />
</cim:BusbarSection>
```

See the Equipment.Equipment.MemberOf_EquipmentContainter is a resource define in a same XML file but somewhere else 
like

```
<cim:VoltageLevel rdf:ID="VL_05" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  xmlns:cim="http://iec.ch/TC57/2001/CIM-schema-cim10#">
<cim:Naming.name>VL_0.22_1</cim:Naming.name>
<cim:VoltageLevel.MemberOf_Substation rdf:resource="#Substation_01" />
<cim:VoltageLevel.BaseVoltage rdf:resource="#BaseVoltage_02" /></cim:VoltageLevel>
```

In my C# code, i have class structure Like

```
  [XmlType("BusbarSection", Namespace = "http://iec.ch/TC57/2001/CIM-schema-cim10#")] 
   public class BusbarSection:Connector 
   {
       public BusbarSection()
       {
       }

   }
    public class Connector:Core.ConductingEquipment
   {

      public Connector()
      {
      }

   }
   public class ConductingEquipment:Equipment 
    {
        //functions and constcturess...
    }
    public class Equipment:PowerSystemResource
   {
       [XmlElement("Equipment.MemberOf_EquipmentContainer")]
       public EquipmentContainer MemberOf_EquipmentContainer; 

       public Equipment()
       {
       }

   }

public class EquipmentContainer:PowerSystemResource
{

    public Topology.ConnectivityNode[] ConnectivityNodes;
    public Equipment[] Contains_Equipments; 

    public EquipmentContainer()
    {

    }

}
```

I am trying to serialize the xml file, it is working good but the elements with as resource EquipmentContainer is coming null.

I am not sure how to serialize xml elements that are as resources in xml. I am missing some concepts in serialization of xmls in c# , i couldn't find how to look for help / Google this question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the XML Serializer is not a complete tool for serializing and deserializing all XML. In this case, I think you'll have to "do it yourself". The XML Serializer doesn't handle references (which is what you have here). Look at [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks. I spent good time developing UML structures and coding. Everything is good until i hit this resource reference issue.

Comment: That should be a hint. Modeling should be interspersed with coding, testing, and release. Otherwise you can wind up with a beautiful model which cannot be implemented.

Comment: @JohnSaunders very true.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with RDF, why not use an RDF library? RDF can be serialised as XML, but as described in e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182777/1445526), there are several ways to do so. For example, the `rdf:ID` attributes can be replaced by `rdf:about` - that could break your parser.

The .Net library for working with RDF [dotnetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/) could be of interest to you.